# Moodle grade_grades table

Tags: moodle

I set a scorm activity to record the highest grade and completed the activity. The grade_grades table has the timestamp when the activity was completed. However, I then changed the attempts management to last completed attempt and completed the activity again (I intend to capture the latest completion date). The grade_grades table's timemodified column did not change. Any ideas why this might be the case or in other words - what happens before an activity data is entered into the grade_grades table and what should I do to ensure that the latest score is captured in the grade_grades table.

Moodle version 2.6

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues came up with multiple SCORM attempts and 2.6 - here's a couple threads with ideas that may help:

1. Forcing new attempt:
   https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=259652
2. Possible attempt-related bug in core code (includes fix suggestion):
   https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=262185

One final idea - does your scorm_scoes_track table reflect the latest attempt?
 If no, could signal a potential issue with some element of the SCORM package itself or activity settings.  If yes, perhaps something more like #2 where the attempt data is not being passed to the grade_grades table.

Hope one of these is helpful.